# copy each file to each folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm very impressed with your knowledge level.

My question is:

I have a folder with 31 MP3 files, one to each day of the month.

I need a batch to create folders named 01 02....31 and copy the 01.mp3
to 01 folder, 02.mp3 to 02 folder and so forth.
This is possible in the windows server 2k8 r2 command?

I try to use the following:

```
FOR /F %%j in (filelist.txt) do (
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%i in (filelist.txt) do (
xcopy %%j e:\%%i\
))
```

And a lot of others...
But the batch creates 31 folders with 31 MP3 files on each folder.

Best Regards.
          Leopoldo.

Comment: I'm very impressed with your question :)

Comment: Hey! why You don't answer my question?!

Comment: What don't you like in `MD 01` then `copy 01.mp3 01` then again `MD 02` then `copy 02.mp3 02` then again ....?

Comment: Forgive me I have about 3 days learning for, set, and other commands.

Answer (score 2):

You have nested loops, each of which goes through the entire list of files. That is why you end up with 31 folders each containing 31 file.

Instead, you should probably process the list just once. Try this:

```
FOR /F %%j IN (filelist.txt) DO XCOPY %%j E:\%%~nj\
```

The `~n` modifier changes the value of `%%j` so it evaluates to name only (`01.mp3` -> `01`).

Read help on the `FOR` command (`FOR /?`) to get more information about modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was the first result on google and Andriy's example does not work. Here is an actually working result

```
for /r "%CD%" %%f in (.) do (copy "filelist.txt" "%%~ff" > nul)
```

Credit to [extramaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021777/2009282)